# Colorize symbols with lstdefinelanguage in latex

Tags: symbols, listings, keywords, lstdefinestyle

I want to put some symbols in green color with lstdefinelanguage in latex, but it seems that symbols are not recognized.

The symbols I need to be colored are =, > and <. Is it possible? How can I do this?

**The main file:**

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{graphicx,color}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{listings}


\lstdefinelanguage{NeoIDL}{
  sensitive = true,
  keywords = [1]{module, resource, enum, annotation, for, import, entity, path,
  @get, @post, @put, @delete, require, ensure, otherwise, call},
  %ndkeywords={int, \char{}  },
  %ndkeywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
  morekeywords=[2]{>, <, ==},
  keywordstyle=[2]\color{green},
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\scriptsize,
  stepnumber=1,
  numbersep=8pt,
  showstringspaces=false,
  breaklines=true,
  frame=top,
  comment=[l]{//},
  morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},
  commentstyle=\color{purple}\ttfamily,
  stringstyle=\color{red}\ttfamily,
  morestring=[b]',
  morestring=[b]"
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{small}
\lstinputlisting[language=NeoIDL,firstnumber=1]{store_pos_servico.neo}
\end{small}
\caption{Service 1}
\end{figure} 

\end{document}
```

**The file to be formatted:**

```
module store {
   (...)

   resource order  {
     path = "/order/{id}";

     @post   int postOrder (Order order)
    require (call store.getOrder(id) == "NotFound"),
    otherwise "InvalidPrecondition"
   };
}
```

Comment: (1) welcome,  (2) please provide a full minimal example, such tjøhat we can test your code without having to add anything. That makes it a lot easier to provide advice

Comment: I did it now, @daleif !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found myself in a similar situation, previously, and I was able to solve the problem in this way:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{graphicx,color}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{listings}


\lstdefinelanguage{NeoIDL}{
  sensitive = true,
  keywords={},
  otherkeywords={% Operators
    >, <, ==
  },
  keywords = [2]{module, resource, enum, annotation, for, import, entity, path,
  @get, @post, @put, @delete, require, ensure, otherwise, call},
  keywordstyle=\color{green},
  keywordstyle=[2]\color{blue},% for example
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\scriptsize,
  stepnumber=1,
  numbersep=8pt,
  showstringspaces=false,
  breaklines=true,
  frame=top,
  comment=[l]{//},
  morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},
  commentstyle=\color{purple}\ttfamily,
  stringstyle=\color{red}\ttfamily,
  morestring=[b]',
  morestring=[b]"
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{small}
\lstinputlisting[language=NeoIDL,firstnumber=1]{store_pos_servico.neo}
\end{small}
\caption{Service 1}
\end{figure} 

\end{document}
```

That is, define an empty set of class-1 keywords, add the symbols as “other keywords” belonging to this class, and shift all other types of keywords to higher order classes.  But don’t ask why this works,  because I don’t know either!

Here is the output I get:

[image: Output of the code]

Comment: Excellent, @Gustavo Mezzeti! I don't need to know how it works, too  :). Only one more question: Is it possible to colorize the symbols of left and right parenthes '(' ')'?

Comment: @LucasLima: I’m sorry, the other times simply adding `, (, )` to the `otherkeywords` list worked like a charm, but it seems that, in your example, the closing parenthesis is not recognized.  Since, as I said, I cannot explain why the trick works when it works, I cannot explain why it doesn’t when it doesn’t either. (:-)