# multiple classes not working with otherkeywords in listings package

Tags: listings

I'm using the listings package to format some code.  The language isn't one of the ones supported out of the box, so I provided my own language definition using `\lstdefinelanguage` as described in the docs for the package.  The problems is that most of the things I want to highlight are non-letter symbols and I want to highlight them into several classes.  Here is my definition:

```
\lstdefinelanguage{mylang}{%
  keywordsprefix={\#},%
  alsoletter={\#},%
  otherkeywords={[,],<,>,<!,!>,.\,},
  otherkeywords={[2]:=,:+},%
  morecomment=[l]\%,
  morestring=[b]",%
  morestring=[d]',%
  sensitive=true%
}
```

You can see that I'm trying to highlight words marked with a # and some punctuation-based symbols.  The issue is that because my "keywords" are based on punctuation, I have to use otherkeywords instead of morekeywords.  And using a second list of otherkeywords doesn't seem to work---I don't get any error, but I don't see any result when trying to apply a style.  I define some colors, then try to assign them to keywords and keywords[2], but to no avail:

```
% Define Colors
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{42,0.0,255}
\definecolor{green}{RGB}{63,127,95}
\definecolor{purple}{RGB}{127,0,85}
\definecolor{orange}{RGB}{225,100,0}

\lstset{
  language={mylang}, % 
  commentstyle=\color{green}, % style of comments
  stringstyle=\color{blue}, % style of strings
  keywordstyle=\color{purple}, % style of keywords
  keywordstyle={[2]\color{orange}} % style of 2nd keywords
}
```

I thought about trying to adding these punctuation symbols into alsoletter, and then using morekeywords instead of otherkeywords.  This partially solves the problem, because I can get multiple styles using the `[2]` indexes on morekeywords, however the issue is now that after making these into letters, the parser won't find them when they're sitting next to a word without whitespace separating.  Making them letters means that the `blah].` won't find the `]` or the `.`.

Any thoughts or ideas?  I started looking through the developers guide but maybe a better idea would be just to look at the source code and see if I can extend the `[index]` functionality to otherkeywords.

In case it's helpful, the language has statements that look like this:

```
a := b & c &
 [ D #e,
   F #e & g,
   H [ I <! k, l !> ]].
```

I'd like to be able to show the "hashtagged" items in a different color from the delimiters, and ideally the operators like `:=` and `&` `.` in a third color.

I've been using xelatex but I don't guess that's relevant.

---

EDIT:

Comments have requested a compilable example, which makes sense, here you go:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
% Define Colors
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{42,0.0,255}
\definecolor{green}{RGB}{63,127,95}
\definecolor{purple}{RGB}{127,0,85}
\definecolor{orange}{RGB}{225,100,0}
\definecolor{gray}{RGB}{150,150,150}


\lstdefinelanguage{mylang}{%
  keywordsprefix={\#},%
  alsoletter={\#},%
  otherkeywords={[2]<,>,[,],<!,!>,.\,},
  otherkeywords={[3]:=,:+},%
  morecomment=[l]\%,
  morestring=[b]",%
  morestring=[d]',%
  sensitive=true%
}


\begin{document}


\lstset{
  language={mylang},
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  commentstyle=\color{green}, % style of comments
  stringstyle=\color{blue}, % style of strings
  keywordstyle=\color{purple}, % style of keywords
  keywordstyle={[2]\color{orange}}, % style of 2nd keywords
  keywordstyle={[3]\color{gray}}, % style of 3nd keywords
  morekeywords={}
}


\begin{lstlisting}
% this is a comment 
a := b & c &
 [ D #e,
   F #e & g,
   H [ I <! k, l !>,
       M "nop" ]].
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Hopefully the example makes clear that the intention here is to highlight the brackets and the `:=` `:+` operators in two different styles, according to the idiom of using `[i]`, to group items and style them---as described in the package documentation.

When I compile this simple example, I see the styling on the comment, on the string and on the `#e`, but nothing on the `otherkeywords` either [2] or [3].  Like this:

[image]

Some workaround which I tried was to add the punctuation symbols to alsoletter, but this actually causes other unwanted behavior (the inability to parse `]].` as a series of three `keywords`).

Aside:

the line in \lstset which says `morekeywords={}` is required to get this to compile.  I think it has to do with the prefix being assigned to keywords then not having any keywords (some kind of interaction between keywords and otherkeywords.

Love to hear any ideas.

---

EDIT 2:

I've been looking in the listings source, specifically in `lstmisc.sty`, I find these lines:

```
\lst@Key{otherkeywords}{}{%
    \let\lst@otherkeywords\@empty
    \lst@for{#1}\do{%
      \lst@MakeActive{##1}%
      \lst@lExtend\lst@otherkeywords{%
          \expandafter\lst@CArg\lst@temp\relax\lst@CDef
              {}\lst@PrintOtherKeyword\@empty}}}
```

I'm still looking through the developers guide to understand what's happening here, but it looks like there might be an opportunity to pass in a second parameter here to \lst@Key and then use it enable grouping on otherkeywords.

Comment: Please make your code snippets compilable ...

Comment: I cannot look deeply into your question now, but the following question, which I happened to [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/313986) one year ago, *could* be related: [Colorize symbols with lstdefinelanguage in latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/313979).

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti thanks!  In fact, I believe my situation is a little more complicated, but you're right that they are related.  In that case, the author just needed to learn about otherkeywords and use the indexing on keywords.  I'm in a situation where I need more than a single class of otherkeywords, and it doesn't seem to be working "out of the box".  I'm willing to modify listings source code if anyone has any pointers.

Cheers!